# DateTimePicker don't show selected date

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

```
 var dtp = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
 var dtp2 = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date ;

SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Tabledbstatus WHERE Date BETWEEN'" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() + "' and '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString() + "'", conn);

da1.Fill(ds1, "TS1"); 

dv1 = new DataView(ds1.Tables["TS1"]);

dataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables["TS1"];
```

Example : I select date 01-09-2016 to 03-09-2016 don't show date 01-09-2016 but show 02-09-2016 to 03-09-2016

*** I want show date 01-09-2016  to 03-09-2016 ***

Comment: Try with dateTimePicker(x).Value.Date.ToString() on the clausule, DateTimePicker selects date AND time, try to use just the date part.

Comment: Have you tried `dtp.AddDays (-1.0);` ? This will subtract one day to your first date, so *02-09-2016* would be *01-09-2016*.

Comment: I tried dtp.AddDays (-1.0); value null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may cause datetime field, you shall try to select date adding hours from to.

```
SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Tabledbstatus WHERE Date BETWEEN'" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() + " 00:00:00' and '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString() + " 23:59:59'", conn);
```

**Edit:**
As it makes the problem for you at first date, you could try something like this:

```
// after line
var dtp = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
// add 
dtp = dtp.AddDays(-1.0);
```

Comment: Take look at Mark Benovsky answer in comment of your post. He's right if that's the problem.

Comment: dtp = dtp.AddDays(-1.0); - try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this line of code:

```
SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Tabledbstatus WHERE Date BETWEEN'" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() + "' and '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString() + "'", conn);
```

to

```
SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Tabledbstatus WHERE Date BETWEEN'" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString() + "' and '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.Date.AddDays(1).ToString() + "'", conn);
```

It will get the value between 01-09-2016 00.00.00 AM to 04-09-2016 00.00.00 AM if you select 01-09-2016 for dateTimePicker1 and 03-09-2016 for dateTimePicker2

Comment: I try it get value between 01-09-2016 00.00.00 AM to 04-09-2016 00.00.00 AM  from select  01-09-2016 to 03-09-2016  but I want to get between 01-09-2016 00.00.00 AM to 03-09-2016 00.00.00 AM   from select  01-09-2016 to 03-09-2016  possible?

thank you

Comment: So instead of using 
dateTimePicker2.Value.Date.AddDays(1).ToString()
you use
dateTimePicker2.Value.Date.ToString() 
in the query.